# Not able to generate the code coverage result using Devel::Cover

Tags: perl, devel-cover

I tried to find code coverage for a `c4rgr.pl` test file with [`Devel::Cover`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Cover). I have a `.pm` module sitting in the same area. I am using `perl -MDevel::Cover c4rgr.pl`, which generates a `cover_db` and has a `runs` subdirectory inside.

Inside the `runs` subdirectory, a versionated directory is created every time I run the `Cover` command and a `cover.13` is obtained. This `cover.13` file (I think) has the raw data for code coverage results.

Still, I am unable to get the test results in a HTML output format or on the Terminal screen.

This is what I do:

1. Run the `perl -MDevel::Cover c4rgr.pl`

   Here, the `c4rgr.pl` uses a .pm module which is sitting in the same area.
2. When I run above command, it runs the test file but no test coverage output as shown in `Devel::Cover` HTML output is obtained. Nevertheless, the `cover.13` file is created every time.

   `Cover.13` <- `1401378982.24872.12631` <- runs <- `cover_db` .
3. Can someone tell me how to get the HTML file, please? I was able to run a dummy test with the same features and generate a HTML file. But with my actual test, it does not. Or is there a way to convert the `cover.13` file to HTML that is not being done in my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After running `perl -MDevel::Cover c4rgr.pl`, run the [cover](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?cover) command.  For example:

```
cover -report html -outputdir cover_report
```

Answer (score -1):

If [@toolic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197758/toolic) solution is not working, you can also try this. Go to terminal and

```
setenv PERL5OPT "-MDevel::Cover"
perl script_name.pl
unsetenv PERL5OPT
cover -report html (or json if you need)
```

This solution works very fine.
Note: Run all these in the terminal.